# Find all linear operators $ \widehat{A}\in\mathbb{V}_2$ which satisfy $\operatorname{ker}{\widehat{A}} = \operatorname{im}{\widehat{A}}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Well, the point is to find all linear operators $\widehat{A}$ that satisfy the following conditions:

- $\operatorname{ker}{\widehat{A}} =  \operatorname{im}{\widehat{A}}$ and
- $\widehat{A} : \mathbb{V}_2  \longrightarrow \mathbb{V}_2, \widehat{A}  \ne \widehat{ \mathcal{O} }$
  where $\widehat{ \mathcal{O}}\left(\overline{x}\right) = \overline{0}, \, \, \, \forall \, \, \overline{x} \in \mathbb{V}_2$.

Hmm... As I see, for both $\operatorname{ker}\widehat{A}$ and $\operatorname{im}\widehat{A}$ $\operatorname{dim}=1$
But...I have quite no idea what to do.
Any help?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{V}_2$ here?

Comment: @CameronWilliams It's a vector space of geometric vectors with $ \operatorname{dim}{\mathbb{V}_2}=2$, which is quite obvious, isn't it?

Comment: @Lebesgue That's not obvious at all. This does not appear to be standard notation.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Well, I'm sorry in that case. It has always been a standard notation in my country, thus it's kinda new to me. Ok. Didn't know that anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a basis $\{u,v\}$ for $\mathbb{V}_2$, and define your operator as
$$\hat{A}u=v$$
$$\hat{A}v=0$$

Now you need to prove two things:

1. Every choice of basis gives an operator that satisfies your conditions.
2. Every operator that satisfies your conditions may be represented in this manner as a basis.

Comment: I think the answer would be a little clearer if you wrote $\hat A u = v$ and $\hat A v = 0$, since OP is using $\hat A$ as the placeholder for the desired operator.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\V}{\mathbb{V}}$
$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}$
**Hint:** Let $A$ be an operator satisfying these criteria.  Since the dimension of the image is $1$, we may state that there exists a $u \in \V_2$ such that for all $x \in \V_2$, we have
$$
A x = \alpha u
$$
for some $\alpha \in \F$.  Now, since $u \in \text{im}(A) \subseteq \ker(A)$, we may state that $Au = \bar 0$.

Let $v$ be any vector that is linearly independent of $u$.  We note that $Av$ cannot be zero.

With the above, we now have enough information to completely describe how $A$ acts over $\V_2$ with respect to the basis $\{u,v\}$.